# ViewPager stucks while swiping views

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have created a viewpager with tabslayout.Each view of viewpager consists of recyclerview inside fragment.The issue i am having is that when i swipe through the views it stucks while swiping in such a manner that there is no change in view and i have to swipe multiple times in order to change view.It looks that swipe event is not detected by viewpager.However if i comment out below two lines which includes setting adapter then i don't experience such issue and swipe is smooth and fast.

```
 PlanListAdapter mAdapter = new PlanListAdapter(browsePlanModelList, getActivity());
 rvBrowsePlanList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Where am i going wrong and how can i resolve this?

Below is code of fragment and adapter-

```
public class FullTimeFragment extends Fragment {



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_browse_plan_list, container, false);

        ArrayList<BrowsePlanModel> browsePlanModelList = (ArrayList<BrowsePlanModel>) getArguments().getSerializable(AppConstant.BROWSEPLANlIST);

        RecyclerView rvBrowsePlanList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvBrowsePlanList);
        //rvBrowsePlanList.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerIncludingLastItemDecoration(getResources()));
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rvBrowsePlanList.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        rvBrowsePlanList.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        if(browsePlanModelList!=null)
        {
            BrowsePlanListAdapter mAdapter = new BrowsePlanListAdapter(browsePlanModelList, getActivity());
            rvBrowsePlanList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

Adapter

```
public class PlanListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlanListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {


    private List<BrowsePlanModel> planList;
    Context mContext;

    public PlanListAdapter(List<BrowsePlanModel> planList, Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.planList = planList;
    }

    @Override
    public PlanListAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.sffs_item, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PlanListAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {


        holder.xyz.setText(planList.get(position).getxyx());
        holder.abc.setText(planList.get(position).getabc());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return planList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView xyz, abc;


        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            xyz = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.xyz);
            abc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.abc);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
myViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(number of pages in your viewpager minus 1);
```

If you do not do this, the pages which are not currently visible will be destroyed and will be recreated every time you swipe. This will lead to huge lag if each of those pages is populating a RecyclerView from a database, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It may be happening because of high resolution image. If you use high resolution images then the viewPager will stuck while swiping . Try using low resolution images.

Comment: i am using no images.only textview in recyclerview item